# How many vendors should I assign to my markets?

Tags: banished

I started playing Banished again during this latest beta release. I was curious about vendors in the market. I didn't used to use the markets before, but I find it is a great storage facility and vendors stockpiling it with goods is great.

However, I was curious about the optimal amount of vendors needed in the market. It starts out with 12 by default, but I quickly lower this to 1/1, because that is all that seems to be needed as my one vendor is keeping that market fully stocked with no issues. Is there some kind of population to vendor ratio that should be maintained for the best results? Or is it a more raise the vendors if they seem to be slacking in resources?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check how full your markets are: if they don't dip very low in terms of percentage full, then there is no need to use more than one citizen as a vendor. Distance to storage barns is also a factor - if the market is far from the supply of goods, it may be difficult for a single vendor to quickly fill up the market, and you might need to add a second vendor sooner than you would normally.

Here, you can see in my decently sized town, this market surrounded by homes now needs two vendors to keep up with the demand of goods.

[image: Vendor count with large town]

Comment: Nice, thanks. I haven't gotten a town nearly that large in size yet, but it's good to know that the vendors will scale slowly overtime. I didn't really want to dedicate half my manpower to selling goods. I'll keep an eye on the stockpile as my town grows.